# remove double quotes that group values together in csv

Tags: java, arrays, csv, split

I hope the title makes sense...

Basically I'm reading in a csv like so:

"blank", "hello", "\"John, Bob\", \"Rudy, Judy\"", "something", "here"

So ideally I'd want to store that into an array that results like this:

```
    // I'm going to use { } to separate the indexes so it'll be easier to read
    // each of these indexes will eventually be stored into their own array - they can contain multiple values 
    // e.g like John, Bob and Rudy, Judy - they'll be in the same array but will be in index 0 and 1 and so on
    [{"blank"}, {"hello"}, {"John, Bob", "Rudy, Judy"}, {"something"}, {"here"}]
```

When I print out the values of the array, it should be something like this:

```
    ...
    System.out.println(item)

    // results in: 
    blank
    hello
    John, Bob
    Rudy, Judy
    ...
```

I have something like this in my code:

```
    cand2 = (!csv2DArray[i][j].equals(" ")) ? csv2DArray[i][j].split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)") : new String[0];
    System.out.print("Candidate2 for current contest is: ");
    for(String item: cand2) { System.out.println(item); }
    ...
```

But I'm getting this when I print out the values:

```
    blank
    hello
    "John, Bob"
    "Rudy, Judy"
    ...
```

How can I remove the double quotes that stick with the values?

Does this make sense? I'm basically trying to compare values (selenium UI testing). So it'll read whatever is on a website, store those values in array and I'll compare.

What's pulled from UI

```
    ["John, Bob", "Rudy, Judy", ...] 
    // when I check the debugger the values become 
    John, Bob, Rudy, Judy...
```

What results from my code

```
    [""John, Bob"", ""Rudy, Judy"", ...]
    // when I check the debugger the values become
    "John, Bob", "Rudy, Judy", ...
```

Comment: If you're reading CSV, it's best to get a parser.  There are several free on the 'net.  You can do it, sorta, with regex, but regex can only handle a limited number of nested delimiters (like the quote marks) before it fails.

Comment: Why? Why not just get rid of the quotes altogether after you've split the lines into cells? You only need them when you write CSV output.

Comment: I used the quotes because I wanted to group John, Bob together with Rudy, Judy. Because they're in the same column in the csv, they'll be placed into the same array. The problem is the double quotes that were used to group those two names together remain in the array

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for(String item: cand2) { System.out.println(item.replace ("\"", ""); }
```

Comment: Doing this results in something like this: John Bob Rudy Judy.. I need it to remain John, Bob Rudy, Judy.. Because of the regex used in the split, if I remove the \" it'll split the commas that were inside those double quotes